# My Flutter App Api Captured with HTTP CARNARY

Tags: php, flutter

my app api is captured with http carnary app which the hacker could access the api.

Is http request authorization could prevent it?

Basic xxxxxxx

I dont know where to ask. Been strugling for days without result.

Answer (score 0):

Disable HTTP without TLS on your server, use certificate pinning on the client. The attacker will only be able to see requests (by reverse engineering or modifying the application). There is no way to be 100% secure in this case. If the user has network access he will be able to see the data. HTTPS and certificate pinning will be reasonable big obstacle for most attackers.